# How to test if React component is returning null or its children using React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component that returns its `children` to be rendered by React if the prop `isTrue` is truth-y. If its prop `isTrue` is false-y, then the component returns `null`, and React doesn't render anything.

I need to test it as a component, mount it, pass the prop, and test if it's children is getting rendered when the prop `isTrue` is truth-y, or we are getting `null` if `isTrue` is false-y.

Here is my component:

```
const RenderIf = ({ isTrue, children }) => {
    if (isTrue) {
        return children;
    }
    return null;
}
export default RenderIf
```

Comment: That isn't doing anything any vanilla function wouldn't, there's no React in there; it's unclear what problem you've had testing it without Enzyme. `expect(RenderIf({ isTrue: false, children [] })).toBeNull()`, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm taking about test it as a component, mount the component, pass the prop,  with a JSX children element, and test if the children is there when is true or if false, then check is null

Comment: Then what are you using for this in other components if *not* Enzyme. React Testing Library, for example?

Comment: Yes they are using react testing library

Comment: So did you try reading the docs for the tool you're actually using? Why mention that you're not using Enzyme, rather than what you *are* using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd think in this case it is probably ok to test the whole html.
react-testing-library wraps your content with a single div so you could something like that:

```
const { container } = render(<MyComponent ifTrue={false}>Content</MyComponent>);
expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<div></div>');
```

If you don't like this approach, you can still render a children with a test-id / text and query it to see if it's present.

Answer (score 49):

```
const { container } = render(<RenderIf isTrue={false}>Content</RenderIf>)

expect(container).toBeEmptyDOMElement()
```

Comment: Note that `container` is obtained as shown in the other answers: `const {container} = render(<></>)`

Comment: This needs more explaination. I just get "property 'toBeEmptyDOMElement' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<string>"

Answer (score 5):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
//...

describe('TestHistory', () => {
  it('should render nothing if there are no history entries', () => {
    // ARRANGE
    // ACT
    const { container } = render(
      <TestHistory version={1} versionHistory={[]} datasetType={DatasetType.VALIDATION} />,
    );

    // ASSERT
    expect(container).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
expect(container.innerHTML).toEqual('');
```

Comment: Your answer needs some expalination.

Answer (score 1):

@ecraig12345 solution will work fine for web.
This will work for both web and react-native:

```
const { toJSON } = render(<RenderIf isTrue={false}>Content</RenderIf>);
expect(toJSON()).toBeNull();
```

A better solution, if we follow `@testing-library` principles, we should test the way an user would test the UI:

```
const mockContent = 'mockContent';
const { queryByText } = render(<RenderIf isTrue={false}>{mockContent}</RenderIf>);
expect(queryByText(mockContent)).toBeNull(); // use screen.queryByText() for Web
```

Comment: It works for React Native